# Getting "no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)" while working with ARGV evaluating in another .rb file

Tags: ruby, command-line, argv

Below is my ruby project to add two numbers:

## feature file:

```
Given the input "2+3"
When the calculation takes place
Then the output should be "5"
```

## step definition file:

```
Given(/^the input "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|
  @input = arg1
end

When(/^the calculation takes place$/) {
  @output = `ruby calculation.rb #{@input}`
}

Then(/^the output should be "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg2|
  assert_equal(@output,arg2)
end
```

## calculation.rb file:

```
print eval(ARGV[0])
```

I get the below error message: Can anyone help me get rid of this?
Everything seems to be in order but facing errors:

## OUTPUT:

```
C:\RubymineProjects\testing>cucumber
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
C:/RubymineProjects/testing/features/calculation.rb:1:in `eval'
C:/RubymineProjects/testing/features/calculation.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:232:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:99:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:262:in `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:65:in `run!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby21/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please treat calc.rb and calculation.rb as same files... typo from my side

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with this code. Have you inspected the value of `@input` within your `When` step?

Comment: Yes... it is returning nil!  Not sure the reason.. Will be good if some one tell me why it is returning nil

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not passing it an argument from the command line, so `ARGV[0]` is `nil`, and that is passed to `eval`, which expects a string instead. To get rid of the error, pass something from the command line.